# rails passing in id parameter ambiguous

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

If I have a route:

```
/users/9/follow
```

`"9"` comes in like this:

```
Parameters: {"id"=>"9"}
```

But if I have a route:

```
/images/6936/like
```

then parameter has image appended to it:

```
Parameters: {"image_id"=>"6936"}
```

Just wondering how I should know if it's `id` or `resourcename_id`.

Comment: Please show us your routes.rb

Comment: And your question is an ambiguous question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extract from [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)

> #### 2.10.1 Adding Member Routes
>
> To add a member route, just add a member block into the resource
>   block:
>
> ```
> resources :photos do
>   member do
>     get 'preview'
>   end
> end
> ```
>
> This will recognize **/photos/1/preview** with **GET**, and route to
>   the preview action of PhotosController, with the resource id value
>   passed in `params[:id]`. It will also create the **preview_photo_url**
>   and **preview_photo_path** helpers.
>
> Within the block of member routes, each route name specifies the HTTP
>   verb that it will recognize. You can use get, patch, put, post, or
>   delete here. If you don't have multiple member routes, you can also
>   pass :on to a route, eliminating the block:
>
> ```
> resources :photos do
>   get 'preview', on: :member
> end
> ```

And the actual answer to your question is in the last paragraph:

> You can leave out the `:on` option, this will create the same member
>   route except that the resource id value will be available in
>   `params[:photo_id]` instead of `params[:id]`.